# Table foot note not showing

Tags: tables, footnotes

I am trying to use footnotes in a table, and I saw a regular `\footnote{}` wouldn't work, but `\tablefootnote{}` should be used instead, therefore importing its package.

I did that, but the footnote is not showing anyway:

```
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

...

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}
{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cellcenter{\thead{Item}} & \cellcenter{\thead{Unit}} & \cellcenter{\thead{Quantity}} & \cellcenter{\thead{Unit Value} & \cellcenter{\thead{Total Value}} \\ \hline

Zenefits HHRR & €/ud. & 0\tablefootnote{Zenefits is free} & 20 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I am getting no errors. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing a compilable document at first that we could use ;-) And `\centering` inside of `center` environment is also not really useful

Comment: You provide only sniped of code which can not be compiled. Please, make it as complete document with all used packages and eventually new command definitions.

Comment: The document is compilable, as I said it has no errors and the pdf is generated correctly. What do you mean?

Comment: @dabadaba: **We** can't compile it because it misses packages, documentclass. Where's `\cellcenter` from, for example?

Comment: Oh okay, updated and it should compile for you since it doesn't use extra packages.

Comment: Soori, but you use extra packages. Without them your code can not be compiled. See answer below.

Comment: @dabadaba: This is not Quantum field theory, so it's easy to provide a compilable example, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more extended comment than answer:

- you show as only code snipped, which can not be compiled (see above comments)
- `tablefootnote` works only in table environment
- environment `\begin{center}\centering ...\end{center}` is strange
- the way of use `\thead{}` nullify the column type `m{...}`
- etc

With  MWE below I got the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell,tablefootnote}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
%\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|M{.2\textwidth}|*{4}{M{.1\textwidth}|}}
    \hline
\thead{Item}    &   \thead{Unit}
                        &   \thead{Quantity}
                                &   \thead{Unity\\ Value}
                                        &   \thead{Total\\ Value} \\
    \hline
Zenefits HHRR   & €/u.  & 0\tablefootnote{Zenefits is free but includes underlying provider pricing.}
                                & 20    & 0                     \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
    \toprule
\thead{Item}    &   \thead{Unit}
                        &   \thead{Quantity}
                                &   \thead{Unity\\ Value}
                                        &   \thead{Total\\ Value} \\
    \midrule
Zenefits HHRR   & €/u.  & 0\tablefootnote{Zenefits is free but includes underlying provider pricing.}
                                & 20    & 0                     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

The footnote appear at bottom of page (not shown on picture). If you like to have them at the table, than this is not right way to do this.

**Edit:** I forgot to mentioned before, that MWE has two solution,. One which follows your code snipped and one, which use rules from `booktabs` package (which for your design is not needed). The purpose of the second case is only to show other possible (more nice) table design.